Telethon. Проблема использования сохранённой сессии
В БД сохранена сессия авторизации телеграм в виде текстового поля (postgres.TEXT).
При попытке подключиться к тг-серверу с использованием данной сессии клиент снова просит задать номер телефона и код авторизации. Делаю согласно документации:
    session_data = get_session_from_db(args.phone_number)
    if session_data:
        api_id, api_hash, session_bytes = session_data
        
        # session_str = '1ApWapzMBu...cY='
        
        phone = prefect.blocks.system.String.load("phone")
        client = TelegramClient(StringSession(session_bytes), api_id, api_hash)
            
        with client:
            tg_channel = client.get_entity(args.tg_channel_name)
            save_channel_to_db(tg_channel.id, tg_channel.title, session_data[0])
            print("Channel saved to database.")
    else:
        print("No active session found for the given phone number.")

